# worldclim: "Current conditions (interpolations of observed data, representative of 1960-1990)"

Tags: data, climate

I am interested in work with climate data since 2012, I found it in  http://www.worldclim.org/version1, but there is something draws my attention:

There it says: "***Current conditions (interpolations of observed data, representative of 1960-1990)***"

1. Does it mean the **current** data is something like a "temporal projection" based in data of 1960-1990?

or

2. Should I understand it like an interpolation of weather stations existing since 1960 with not including stations existing since 1990?

Comment: I think that this is a question that may be more suitable for researching at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that current is not "now". At best, its current to the publication date. `Hijmans, R.J., S.E. Cameron, J.L. Parra, P.G. Jones and A. Jarvis, 2005. Very high resolution interpolated climate surfaces for global land areas.`. So **2005** 'current'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [methods](http://www.worldclim.org/methods1) in the 3rd paragraph of your [link](http://www.worldclim.org/version1) state:

> The data layers were generated through interpolation of average
>   monthly climate data from weather stations on a 30 arc-second
>   resolution grid (often referred to as "1 km2" resolution). Variables
>   included are monthly total precipitation, and monthly mean, minimum
>   and maximum temperature, and 19 derived bioclimatic variables.
>
> [snip...]
>
> For stations for which we had records for multiple years, we
>   calculated averages for the 1960-90 period. We only used records for
>   which there were at least 10 years of data. In some cases we extended
>   the time period to the 1950-2000 period to include records from areas
>   for which we had few recent records available (e.g., DR Congo) or
>   predominantly recent records (e.g., Amazonia).

So your 2nd option is closest. They averaged records for each month for each climate variable for the period 1960-1990 (with some exceptions), then spatially interpolated the averages and called that "current".